# PowerQuery M - How to refer to a column name that as an apostrophe?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a column name such as Titre d'emploi, and when i refer to it as [Titre d'emploi], it gives me an error and i tried multiple things like ["Titre d'emploi"], and i googled for quite a while but nothing really applies.

Would you guys have any idea of how to refer to it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be similar to the automatically generated step names in the advanced editor:

```
[#"Titre d'emploi"]
```

You should be able to discover this yourself by looking at the code generated when you do something to that column. For example, if you choose Transform > Statistics > Count Values, then you'll get code like this:

```
= List.NonNullCount(#"Previous Step Name Here"[#"Titre d'emploi"])
```

Comment: Ah yes! thanks for the tips, it works. I've been looking for hours !

Comment: Or you can right click the column -> drill down, and it'll generate the same name